# Trigger ng-change not for default value Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

In drop down, the default select value is 'Select Customer' and has list of customer names. Ng-change should trigger only for customer names not for the 'Select Customer' value. we can do it in controller, but is there any way to do it in html/view.

```
<Select ng-options="o.cusid in o.cusname for o in custcollections ng-model="modeldata" ng-change="getcusdetails(modeldata)">
<option value=""> Select Customer</option>
</select>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a check in **ng-change** to call controller function based on condition. Your code would be something like:

```
<select ng-options="o.cusid in o.cusname for o in custcollections ng-model="modeldata" ng-change="modeldata===undefined || getcusdetails(modeldata)"><option value=""> Select Customer</option>
```

In above snippet, look at the ng-chnage it is : **`ng-change="modeldata===undefined || getcusdetails(modeldata)"`** . So whenever you select 'Select Customer' value of modeldata would be undefined so function will not get called. When you select other values modeldata would be not undefined so the function in ng-change will get called.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Select ng-options="o.cusid in o.cusname for o in custcollections ng-model="modeldata" ng-change=" modeldata!='default' && getcusdetails(modeldata)">
<option value=""> Select Customer</option>
</select>
```

The other option can be to do it in controller:

```
 $scope.getcusdetails = function(selected) {
    if(selected=='default') return;
     //your code
}
```